# Distinguish between solaris and Linux server while loading the page

Tags: xml, linux, solaris

We have one application which when hit shows the list of servers. Currently these servers are on solaris machine and while hitting the url it shows all these servers list. These all servers are maintained in a xml file in the below formats.

```
<servers>
    <serverGroup>egmk</serverGroup>
    <server>
        <ident>egmk-process-daemon</ident>
        <pid>egmk-process</pid>
        <runFlag>keep</runFlag>
        <title>Process Daemon</title>
        <url>/egmk-process-daemon</url>
        <logDir>/dneg/egmk/egmk-process-daemon/active/log</logDir>
        <startCommand>/dneg/egmk/egmk-process-daemon/active/bin/egmkdaemon.sh,start
        </startCommand>
        <stopCommand>/dneg/egmk/egmk-process-daemon/active/bin/egmkdaemon.sh,stop
        </stopCommand>
    </server>

    <!-- eGMK BECS reconciliation daemon running at 19:10 -->
    <server>
        <ident>egmk-becs-rec-daemon</ident>
        <pid>egmk=becs-rec</pid>
        <title>BECS Reconciliation Daemon</title>
        <url>/egmk-becs-rec-daemon</url>
        <runFlag>once</runFlag>
        <logDir>/dneg/egmk/egmk-becs-rec-daemon/active/log</logDir>
        <startCommand>/dneg/egmk/egmk-becs-rec-daemon/active/bin/egmkdaemon.sh,start
        </startCommand>
        <stopCommand></stopCommand>
    </server>

    <!-- EGMK FX/MM Research Upload Daemon daemon started once a day -->
    <server>
        <ident>egmk-research-upload-daemon</ident>
        <pid>egmk=egmk-research-upload-daemon</pid>
        <runFlag>once</runFlag>
        <title>EGMK FX/MM Research Upload Daemon</title>
        <url>/egmk-research-upload-daemon</url>
        <logDir>/dneg/egmk/egmk-research-upload-daemon/active/log</logDir>
        <startCommand>/dneg/egmk/egmk-research-upload-daemon/active/bin/egmk-research-upload.sh,start
        </startCommand>
        <stopCommand>/dneg/egmk/egmk-research-upload-daemon/active/bin/egmk-research-upload.sh,stop
        </stopCommand>
    </server>
```

Now as a part of new requirement, i have to add a filer or condition based on the environment. if it is solaris, it should show certain list of servers and if it is Linux HVE environment, it should show different servers.

Example :- hitting the url http://abc:8080/abc/ (solaris url)  will show list of few servers while hitting http://def:8084/something/ (Linux url) will shows another set of server lists.

Can you please tell me if it possible to put conditions like this in the xml file ?

Comment: Are the XML files used by any other application?

Comment: No. this xml file not used by any other application and its inctanse is not present in the whole project also. Looks like it picks  the servers directly from xml while loading the page itself.

Comment: any nice soul to help me ?

Comment: Just add an element/attribute denoting where to display each server.